# A view or Layout like GridView

Tags: java, android, gridview, layout, view

I am trying to create a custom view like a GridView but with the difference of scroll bar functionality. i.e. I want that the GridView should create the column and rows dynamically and must hold a TextView or EditText view inside each cell of the grid and the custom view can be scrolled in vertically and horizontally too.

I have been tried with Table and default Grid Layout but I failed. Any idea, suggestion or comments are welcome.

Thank you.

Comment: It is very achieve with RecyclerView, have you tried that?

Comment: No, I haven't tried it with RecyclerView, do you have any hint for me.

Comment: Yes, Let me show you the code.

Comment: ok, I'm waiting for hint.

Comment: With a RecyclerView you just need to create a view with a layout containing a row of views inside of it. Then load that view in onCreateView and manage the individual row of views in onBindView. Think @ShajeelAfzal is coming up with a sample for you, but that is an idea of how you could do it. Not the only way, but one possible way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [RecyclerView](http://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html) for this purpose. You will have to declare the number of Columns upfront. You cannot have different number of columns at runtime.

**However Horizontal and Vertical Scrolling at the same time** is tricky but still can be done.

Checkout: http://belladunovska.com/tech/nested-recycler-view-in-android

There is a talk on the same topic by [Android Lead of NewCircle Training](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gs_C1E8HwvE)

Also you can checkout TwoWayView: https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view (I think it is not using RecyclerView)

Comment: Thanks @ShajeelAfzal, Let me go through you help.